# While using a cardView in a fragment , an error occurs at layout inflater?

Tags: android

The program runs properly , but when i open this fragment , the application crashes .

**HomeFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView homeFeatured = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.featured_home);
    TextView homeFeaturedViewAll = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.featured_view_all_home);
    TextView homeNewReleases = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.new_releases_home);
    TextView homeNewReleasesViewAll = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.new_releases_view_all_home);
    TextView homeTopReads = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.top_reads_home);
    TextView homeTopReadsViewAll = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.top_reads_view_all_home);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

}
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.pratilipi.www.pratilipi.HomeFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:id="@+id/featured_home_layout"
    android:elevation="2dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/featured_home"
        android:text="@string/home_featured"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/featured_view_all_home"
        android:text=">"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Basic CardView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/new_releases_home_layout"
            android:background="#808080"
            android:elevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/new_releases_home"
                android:text="@string/new_releases_home"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/new_releases_view_all_home"
                android:text=">"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/top_reads_home_layout"
            android:background="#808080"
            android:elevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/top_reads_home"
                android:text="@string/home_top_reads"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/top_reads_view_all_home"
                android:text=">"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In error log it points the onCreateView return statement line . Without the card view the app is working properly . Is there some way to solve this ?
What should i do to solve this type of app crash . Thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: can you able to post the log too

Comment: you should post your error log

Comment: Have you import cards library in your gradle file?     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'

Comment: Yes i got it Thanks a lot ! i imported the gradle file and it worked thanks a lot

Comment: Please, check my answer as the accepted in case it is.. I'll post it. Thanks, and you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you import cards library in your gradle file?

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'

After adding this line, sync your gradle project.

Comment: Thanks a ton ! it worked ! But i still get some rendering issues like Missing Styles ? is the correct theme chosen for your layout ?

Comment: If your problem is related to the render... Sometimes the render show problems that don't really exist. Check launching your app in your device. CardViews present some differences in API's below 21 (round corners etc.) because of internal performance issues. Give it some time, and patience. I recommend you to try them in all different API's you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot , ill try in all API's Thank you once again .

Answer (score 0):

You have to inflate the layout first.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

then use

```
  TextView homeFeatured = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.featured_home);
```

and the remaining codes..

Comment: Again there is some rendering problem
Missing styles ? is the correct theme chosen for your layout ? 
This is the error i get .

Answer (score 0):

I imported the gradle files and it worked .